# Php parse html file multiple variables

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, foreach

i want to parse the following HTML via PHP: `https://pastebin.com/raw/5Z59HTcW`
The Problem is that not always one line should be parsed rather always all 3 span elements should be parsed in one foreach

Thats my current code:

```
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

preg_match_all('/<span class="(name|price|description)">(.*)<\/span>/',$json_decoded->results_html, $sor);

foreach($sor[1] as $k => $v)
{
echo "Name" .$v[0]."<br/>";
echo "price" .$v[1]."<br/>";
echo "des" .$v[2]."<br/>";
}
```

Thank you,
with best regards

Comment: you could try with `DOMDocument` & perhaps `DOMXPath`

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument to parse the HTML is fairly straightforward -not even any XPath required in this instance

```
    $url='https://pastebin.com/raw/5Z59HTcW';
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );

    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $span ){
            echo $span->getAttribute('class').' '.$span->nodeValue . '<br />';
        }
    }
```

Outputs:

```
name Test1
description testtest1
price 1 USD
name Test2
description testtest2
price 2 USD
name Test3
description testtest3
price 3 USD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, How can I echo only the name and the price? Regards

Answer (score 0):

we can do a traverse with `loadHTML`

```
$htmlContent = '<span class="name">Test1</span> 
<span class="description">testtest1</span>
<span class="price">1 USD</span>

<span class="name">Test2</span>
<span class="description">testtest2</span>
<span class="price">2 USD</span>

<span class="name">Test3</span> 
<span class="description">testtest3</span>
<span class="price">3 USD</span>';

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');

//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader)
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Header);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<table border="1"><thead><tr><td>Name</td><td>Desc</td><td>Price</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
$lastOne = '';
foreach(array_chunk($aDataTableHeaderHTML,3) as $key=>$v)
 {
    echo "<tr>
           <td>$v[0]</td>
           <td>$v[1]</td>
           <td>$v[2]</td>        
       </tr>";
 }
 echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Output:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 9
 )

Name      Desc      Price
Test1   testtest1   1 USD
Test2   testtest2   2 USD
Test3   testtest3   3 USD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, How can I echo only the name and the price? Regards

Comment: Just remove the <`<td>$v[1]</td>` , it will remove the desc and only name and price  `echo "<tr>
           <td>$v[0]</td>
           <td>$v[2]</td>        
       </tr>";`